# RecyclerView not showing parsed GSON data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, gson

I've gone through a few questions on here and I'm absolutely stuck as to how to proceed. I am parsing data using GSON and I have added the results to my recyclerview in addition to adding the notifydatachange  to the adapter and yet my recycler view is still empty. My logcat shows nothing wrong and is receiving information from the server. Can someone let me know what I have done incorrectly? My RecyclerView adapter seems ok and I think I added the necessary codes to my fragment.

Fragment Activity:

```
 public class WeatherAppFragment extends Fragment implements Listener {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private SearchView searchView = null;
private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
String mStatusView;
List<ForecastWeatherList> items = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;




        @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weather_app, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    Log.d("debugMode", "I'm in onCreateView");

    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items, mRecyclerView.getContext());

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    new GetWeatherAync(this, mStatusView, api_key).execute();
    return view;
}


  private class GetWeatherAync extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, List<ForecastWeatherList>> {
    private String TAG = GetWeatherAync.class.getSimpleName();
    private final String serviceUrl;
    private Context mContext;
    private Listener listener;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;


    public GetWeatherAync(Listener listener, Object mStatusView, Object api_key) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.serviceUrl =  "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + "Miami" +"&APPID="+ " ";
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ForecastWeatherList> doInBackground(Context...params) {
        try {
            Log.d("debugMode", "The application is in doInBackground");

            URL url = new URL(serviceUrl);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                // If the request was successful (response code 200),
                // then read the input stream and parse the response.
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Response code:" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    Log.e("response",bufferedReader.toString());
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    if (!bufferedReader.equals("")) {
                        ForecastWeatherListWrapper weatherWrapper = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, ForecastWeatherListWrapper.class);
                        Log.e("something", weatherWrapper.getforecastWeatherLists().size() + "");
                        List<ForecastWeatherList> forecastWeatherLists = weatherWrapper.getforecastWeatherLists();

                        return forecastWeatherLists;
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                    }
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("catch","error");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }


        return null;


    }

       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ForecastWeatherList> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "populate UI recycler view with gson converted data");
            listener.afterSearch(result);
            items.clear();
            items.addAll(result);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();







        } else{
        Log.e(TAG, "Result is null");
        // check if this Log shows up?
    }
}
    }
```

RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
     public class RecyclerViewAdapter  extends    
     RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ForecastRecycler> {

     private List<ForecastWeatherList> mForecastWeatherDataList;
     Context mContext;

public static class ForecastRecycler extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView currentTemp;
    public TextView currentHumidity;
    public TextView currentDescription;
    public ImageView currentIcon;


    public ForecastRecycler (View view) {
        super (view);


        currentTemp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_temperature);
        currentHumidity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_humidity);
        currentDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_weather_description);
        currentIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_weather_icon);

    }

}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ForecastWeatherList> mForecastWeatherDataList,Context mContext) {
    this.mForecastWeatherDataList = mForecastWeatherDataList;

    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ForecastRecycler onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

    return new ForecastRecycler(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( ForecastRecycler holder, int position) {

    final ForecastWeatherList currentRecycler = mForecastWeatherDataList.get(position);

    Log.d("weather", currentRecycler.getWeather().getDescription());


    holder.currentTemp.setText((Double.toString(currentRecycler.getMain().getTemp())));
    holder.currentHumidity.setText(currentRecycler.getMain().getHumidity());
    holder.currentDescription.setText(currentRecycler.getWeather().getDescription());
    Picasso.with(holder.currentIcon.getContext()).load(currentRecycler.getWeather().getIcon());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mForecastWeatherDataList.size();
}

}
```

FragmentWeatherApp:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".WeatherAppFragment">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Recycler Item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_city_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/current_weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_temperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_humidity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_weather_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my forecastweatherlistwrapper:

```
 public class ForecastWeatherListWrapper {

 @SerializedName("list")
 @Expose
 private List<ForecastWeatherList> forecastWeatherLists;

 public List<ForecastWeatherList> getforecastWeatherLists() {
    return forecastWeatherLists;
}

public void setforecastWeatherLists(List<ForecastWeatherList>      
forecastWeatherItems){

   this.forecastWeatherLists = forecastWeatherItems;
       }
}
```

Here is my ForecastWeatherList:

```
public class ForecastWeatherList {
@SerializedName("dt")
@Expose
private Integer dt;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private Main main;
@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private Weather weather = null;
@SerializedName("clouds")
@Expose
private Clouds clouds;
@SerializedName("wind")
@Expose
private Wind wind;
@SerializedName("rain")
@Expose
private Rain rain;
@SerializedName("sys")
@Expose
private Sys sys;
@SerializedName("dt_txt")
@Expose
private String dtTxt;

public Integer getDt() {
    return dt;
}

public void setDt(Integer dt) {
    this.dt = dt;
}

public Main getMain() {
    return main;
}

public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public Weather getWeather() {
    return (Weather) weather;
}

public void setWeather(Weather weather) {
    this.weather = weather;
}

public Clouds getClouds() {
    return clouds;
}

public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
    this.clouds = clouds;
}

public Wind getWind() {
    return wind;
}

public void setWind(Wind wind) {
    this.wind = wind;
}

public Rain getRain() {
    return rain;
}

public void setRain(Rain rain) {
    this.rain = rain;
}

public Sys getSys() {
    return sys;
}

public void setSys(Sys sys) {
    this.sys = sys;
}

public String getDtTxt() {
    return dtTxt;
}

public void setDtTxt(String dtTxt) {
    this.dtTxt = dtTxt;
}



  }
```

Here are my some of  GSON classes to parse JSON data. Some classes are Main, Clouds, etc

Here is my main class:

```
public class Main {

@SerializedName("temp")
@Expose
private Double temp;
@SerializedName("temp_min")
@Expose
private Double tempMin;
@SerializedName("temp_max")
@Expose
private Double tempMax;
@SerializedName("pressure")
@Expose
private Double pressure;
@SerializedName("sea_level")
@Expose
private Double seaLevel;
@SerializedName("grnd_level")
@Expose
private Double grndLevel;
@SerializedName("humidity")
@Expose
private Integer humidity;
@SerializedName("temp_kf")
@Expose
private Integer tempKf;

public Double getTemp() {
    return temp;
}

    public void setTemp(Double temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public Double getTempMin() {
        return tempMin;
    }

    public void setTempMin(Double tempMin) {
        this.tempMin = tempMin;
    }

    public Double getTempMax() {
        return tempMax;
    }

    public void setTempMax(Double tempMax) {
        this.tempMax = tempMax;
    }

public Double getPressure() {
    return pressure;
}

public void setPressure(Double pressure) {
    this.pressure = pressure;
}

public Double getSeaLevel() {
    return seaLevel;
}

public void setSeaLevel(Double seaLevel) {
    this.seaLevel = seaLevel;
}

public Double getGrndLevel() {
    return grndLevel;
}

public void setGrndLevel(Double grndLevel) {
    this.grndLevel = grndLevel;
}

public Integer getHumidity() {
    return humidity;
}

public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
    this.humidity = humidity;
}

public Integer getTempKf() {
    return tempKf;
}

public void setTempKf(Integer tempKf) {
    this.tempKf = tempKf;
}

  }
```

Here is my weather class:

```
public class Weather {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private String main;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMain() {
    return main;
}

public void setMain(String main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}


  }
```

Here is my raw string data (I think).

```
 "cod":"200",
"message":0.0074,
  "cnt":39,
"list":[
  {
     "dt":1534215600,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.24,
        "temp_min":292.346,
        "temp_max":293.24,
        "pressure":1021.77,
        "sea_level":1028.21,
        "grnd_level":1021.77,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.89
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":20
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.51,
        "deg":275.001
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":0.0050000000000008
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 03:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534226400,
     "main":{
        "temp":292.3,
        "temp_min":291.706,
        "temp_max":292.3,
        "pressure":1020.99,
        "sea_level":1027.42,
        "grnd_level":1020.99,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.6
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.52,
        "deg":294.505
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 06:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534237200,
     "main":{
        "temp":291.07,
        "temp_min":290.77,
        "temp_max":291.07,
        "pressure":1020.65,
        "sea_level":1027.03,
        "grnd_level":1020.65,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.3
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":1.31,
        "deg":225.5
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 09:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534248000,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.286,
        "temp_min":293.286,
        "temp_max":293.286,
        "pressure":1020.78,
        "sea_level":1027.17,
        "grnd_level":1020.78,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"02d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":8
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.83,
        "deg":234.501
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 12:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534258800,
     "main":{
        "temp":298.671,
        "temp_min":298.671,
        "temp_max":298.671,
        "pressure":1020.76,
        "sea_level":1027.15,
        "grnd_level":1020.76,
        "humidity":92,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.71,
        "deg":259.5
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 15:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534269600,
     "main":{
        "temp":300.7,
        "temp_min":300.7,
        "temp_max":300.7,
        "pressure":1019.76,
        "sea_level":1026.18,
        "grnd_level":1019.76,
        "humidity":83,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":24
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.66,
        "deg":285.503
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":1.11
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 18:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534280400,
     "main":{
        "temp":298.464,
        "temp_min":298.464,
        "temp_max":298.464,
        "pressure":1019.68,
        "sea_level":1025.97,
        "grnd_level":1019.68,
        "humidity":83,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":48
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.27,
        "deg":289.504
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":1.61
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 21:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534291200,
     "main":{
        "temp":297.882,
        "temp_min":297.882,
        "temp_max":297.882,
        "pressure":1020,
        "sea_level":1026.37,
        "grnd_level":1020,
        "humidity":82,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":36
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.37,
        "deg":275.004
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":0.13
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 00:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534302000,
     "main":{
        "temp":295.242,
        "temp_min":295.242,
        "temp_max":295.242,
        "pressure":1021.11,
        "sea_level":1027.53,
        "grnd_level":1021.11,
        "humidity":94,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":802,
           "main":"Clouds",
           "description":"scattered clouds",
           "icon":"03n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":32
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":1.26,
        "deg":313.002
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 03:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534312800,
     "main":{
        "temp":294.05,
        "temp_min":294.05,
        "temp_max":294.05,
        "pressure":1021.27,
        "sea_level":1027.77,
        "grnd_level":1021.27,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.46,
        "deg":274.504
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 06:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534323600,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.495,
        "temp_min":293.495,
        "temp_max":293.495,
        "pressure":1021.36,
        "sea_level":1027.7,
        "grnd_level":1021.36,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.01,
        "deg":277.505
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 09:00:00"
],
"city":{
  "id":4347778,
  "name":"Baltimore",
  "coord":{
     "lat":39.2909,
     "lon":-76.6108
  },
  "country":"US",
  "population":620961
 }
  }
```

and here is my LogCat:

```
  ksburneytwo.weathertest E/GetWeatherAync: Response code:200
  ksburneytwo.weathertest E/response: java.io.BufferedReader@3d54b14
  ksburneytwo.weathertest E/something: 40
  ksburneytwo.weathertest E/GetWeatherAync: populate UI recycler view with gson converted data
```

Comment: post Json and Model class structure as well and are you getting data.?

Comment: Your `Recycler Item:` layout hight should be **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`**

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi I added the JSON and model class structure. I also added my logcat which is showing something is being extracted from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. The postexecute was sending it to the listener.aftersearch. It was there that the results needed to be sent to the recyclerview in the form of items.addAll(results). The recyclerview now loads.